# Effectively scaling multiple images in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-graphics

I have 15 images being displayed on a single view.  I need to scale the images based on the user's voice (the louder they speak the larger the images need to scale).  At the moment I am using averagePowerForChannel on the AVAudioRecorder and frequently sampling the audio to scaling all the images appropriately.  The code I'm using to do the scaling looks something like this:

```
- (void)scaleImages:(float)scalingFactor {
    for (UIView *imageHolder in self.imageView.subviews) {
        UIView *image = [imageHolder.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scalingFactor, scalingFactor);
        image.hidden = scalingFactor <= 0.0f;
    }
}
```

This works fine when I have a single image, but when I do this for all 15 images it becomes incredibly laggy and unresponsive.  I have tried several different options - sampling less frequently, normalizing the sampling output, etc but nothing seems to make a difference.

How would I optimize this?

Comment: The best performance would come from drawing all of the images into a single image (or OpenGL texture, or ...) then scaling that.  Not many situations where that is possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the GPUImage framework . It uses the GPU to accelerate Core Image transforms .

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: As a minor point, GPUImage and Core Image are separate frameworks. They both do many of the same things, but neither is used inside of the other.